# Error with storage when using NEW disk type in Terraform SQL Server virtual machine setup

Tags: sql-server, azure, terraform, azure-pipelines, azure-rm

I'm trying to add the SQL Server "data"/ "log" disk by using Terraform.
There are 3 data disk created for the VM with luns 0,1,2 each set to Standard SSD with 128G of space in Terraform
[image]

The following snippet is what I am currently trying to run.

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine" "sqlconfig" {

  virtual_machine_id               = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm[var.HOSTNAME_MICROSOFTSQL].id
  sql_license_type                 = "PAYG"
  sql_connectivity_port            = *redacted 
  sql_connectivity_type            = *redacted 
  sql_connectivity_update_password = *redacted 
  sql_connectivity_update_username = *redacted 

  sql_instance {

    collation = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"

  }

  storage_configuration {

    disk_type = "NEW" 
    storage_workload_type = "OLTP"
  
    data_settings {

      default_file_path = "F:\\Data"
      luns = [0]

    }

    log_settings {

      default_file_path = "G:\\Log"
      luns = [1]

    }

    temp_db_settings {

      default_file_path = "G:\\tempDb"
      luns = [1]
      data_file_count = 8
      data_file_size_mb = 8
      data_file_growth_in_mb = 64
      log_file_size_mb = 8
      log_file_growth_mb = 64

    }

  }
```

However, I am getting the following error when deploying from azure devops pipeline

```
 polling after CreateOrUpdate: Code="Ext_StorageConfigurationSettingsError" Message="Error: 'Number of disks found do not match the expected count for creating Storage Pool, found :0 target: 1. Detail: Disk with LUN number 0 cannot be pooled. Reason : Insufficient Capacity'"
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that within Terraform, when creating the Datadisks and attaching them to the VM before running the section on `azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine`, it runs into some kind race condition between setting up the disk/attachment and storage configuration within `azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine`. This problem is solved once we added the following block of code under `azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine`:

```
    depends_on = [
          azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment.[disk_attachment_name]
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

DATA volume seems compatible with PremiumSSD and UltraDisks only. Same for LOGS. Try to change the disk type.

To auick validate, try to create your VM via Azure Portal, when configuring Storage you should only be able to select Ultra or PXX disks.

Hope it helps.

Comment: tried it with Premium SSD still the same error.